Saving polygon layer with custom forms in QGIS
I make a lot of polygons to calculate the area of different land use types in my work. To do this I usually custom form by opening properties > manage custom forms and field editor configuration > fields > defaults > default values where I add $area and check the apply default value on an update to see the changes to the polygons live.
I then use the area field to do some other pretty basic calculations and make them dependent on each other so if I change the polygon size they all change automatically.
What I want to do and haven't figured out what to do: I want to save this layer with the default values so I can copy it into all my projects without having to manually redo all the default values in the properties of the new polygon layers I create in new projects. Ideally, I can copy this one layer into any new projects I make and not have to start from scratch. Is this possible?


You can save the style (button in the lower left corner in your screenshot) of the layer and load it to any other polygon layer. Forms are part of the style and they can be easily reused with the style
